# Python inheritance problem

Tags: python

I'm making a game, and I have some problems... I have a function that loads a map (usually when the player collides with a gate). I have two gates and two maps (one gate on each map). When I walk to a gate the second map is loaded, when I walk through a gate on that map, the first map is loaded. I also have a tree on the first map. Everything works fine unless I click on that tree. This is very strange because I don't have anything that handles that! Nothing should happen! And actually, nothing happens, except when I try to get back from the second map it doesn't work!

This is the error message I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "guilds.py", line 820, in <module>
load_map(objekt.gate_path, objekt.name, False)
File "guilds.py", line 287, in load_map
npc(o[1], o[3])
File "guilds.py", line 147, in __init__
creature.__init__(self, pos, name)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

So there seems to be a problem loading the NPCs from the map (NPC class inherits from the creature class).

HERE ARE THE TWO CLASSES:

a) NPC:

```
class npc(creature):
     def __init__(self, pos, name):
          self.move_target = crt.crt[name]['move_target']

          if 'quest' in crt.crt[name]:
               self.quest_name = crt.crt[name]['quest_name']
               self.move_quest = crt.crt[name]['move_quest']
               self.q_giver = True
          else:
               self.q_giver = False

          self.guild = crt.crt[name]['guild']

          lista_npc.append(self)

          creature.__init__(self, pos, name)
```

b) creature, which NPC inherits from:

```
class creature():
     def __init__(self, pos, name):
          self.pic = []
          self.lista_slika = crt.crt[name]['ls_slk']
          for slika in self.lista_slika:
               self.pic.append(pygame.image.load(slika).convert()) #load the image

          for slika in self.pic:
               self.colorkey = slika.get_at((0,0)) #get the colokey from the first pixel (0,0)
               slika.set_colorkey(self.colorkey, RLEACCEL)

          self.counter = int(time.time())
          self.time = int(time.time())
          self.pos = pos
          self.rect = self.pic[0].get_rect() #get image rectangle
          self.rect = self.rect.move(self.pos) #get the rectangle on the starting position
          self.current_health = crt.crt[name]['health']
          self.max_health = crt.crt[name]['health']
          self.name = name
          self.targeted = False
          self.targeted_3 = False
          lista_creature.append(self)


     def follow(self):
          if self.face == 0:
               self.rect = self.rect.move(NPCspeed_right)
               self.pos = (self.pos[0] + NPCspeed_right[0], self.pos[1] + NPCspeed_right[1])
          if self.face == 1:     
               self.rect = self.rect.move(NPCspeed_left)
               self.pos = (self.pos[0] + NPCspeed_left[0], self.pos[1] + NPCspeed_left[1])

          if self.face == 2:     
               self.rect = self.rect.move(NPCspeed_up)
               self.pos = (self.pos[0] + NPCspeed_up[0], self.pos[1] + NPCspeed_up[1])
          if self.face == 3:     
               self.rect = self.rect.move(NPCspeed_down)
               self.pos = (self.pos[0] + NPCspeed_down[0], self.pos[1] + NPCspeed_down[1])


     def die(self):     
          self.randin = random.randint(-100, 100)
          self.randin2 = random.randint(-100, 100)
          self.pos = (self.pos[0] + self.randin, self.pos[1] + self.randin2)
          self.combat = False
          self.current_health = self.max_health
          self.rect.move_ip(self.randin, self.randin2)
          self.targeted = False

          for quest in lista_quest:
               if quest.target_name == self.name and quest.onit == True:
                    quest.goal -= 1
```

Comment: Can you post some code from `guilds.py` around where the exception is thrown? Can you print `self, pos, name` just before the call to the ctor.

Comment: The code you pasted looks good, are you sure that's all and the right code? Which lines are marked in the traceback?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, I thought it was something in this code... Strange, could you contact me so I can send you some more code? yanncore@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

You have a global variable "creature" which is hiding your class.

Comment: In which class? I don't see it... Contact me on yanncore@gmail.com please :)

Comment: Nevermind, +1. @Yann: You propably have a global variable defined as `creature = creature()` - it's not in the code you showed us, so we can't tell you where. Class names should be upper-case by the way, partially to avoid this problem.

Comment: I love you man! It was true! There is a list of all the creatures, and I did this:
for creature in l_creature:
So I changed the word 'creature' to 'crtr' and it works now! I'll start renaming my classes right away, if that's the standard. So the first letter should be upper case? And if it's more than one word then it's something like this ManBearPig? Thanks again!

Comment: @Yann: See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ for naming convention and other coding style guidelines.

Comment: @Yann: Hehe, glad to be of help. You have no idea how often that happened to me. Nowadays I name all my ClassesLikeThis (and none_of_the_variables). If there's a class (like "object") that isn't LikeThis, I start to feel uneasy ;-)

Comment: Ah, the for loop variable being in the way, classic. 
Funnily enough, the for loop variable will even be there, in the way, _after_ the entire for loop finished... Homage to C?
`for creature in blah:

  pass
# much later then:
creature() # oops` argh how do I enter a newline here?